# Django class view: __init__

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I want to get `<Model>` value from a URL, and use it as an `__init__` parameter in my class.

```
urls.py
url(r'^(?P<Model>\w+)/foo/$', views.foo.as_view(), name='foo_class'),

views.py
class foo(CreateView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        text = kwargs['Model']         # This is not working
        text = kwargs.get('Model')     # Neither this
        Bar(text)
        ...
```

Clearly, I'm missing something, or my understanding of URL `<>` class view is wrong.

Comment: there is no request if you use .as_view(). 'name 'request' is not defined'

Comment: You need to show more details. Where do you want to use these parameters? Usually in Django views overriding `__init__` is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: I want to use generic view CreateView to add objects to model, and pass model name by URL.
ex. To add object to Foo1: xxx/Foo1/foo,  add object to Bar2: xxx/Bar2/foo.
I have class ready, it works with hardcoded inputs, but I can't get it going with kwargs.

Comment: The kwargs are already available throughout as `self.kwargs`. You don't need to assign them anywhere.

Comment: Then it returns 'Foo' object has no attribute 'kwargs'

Comment: *Where* does it do that? As I said, there is no need to override `__init__`, so you shouldn't be doing that there.

Comment: AttributeError at /xxxxx/Bar2/foo/
'foo' object has no attribute 'kwargs'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/xxxxx/Bar2/foo/
Line: model= apps.get_model(app_label='xxxxx', model_name=str(self.kwargs))

Comment: But *where* is that code? You'd probably need to put it in `get_form_class`.

Comment: Sorry, Daniel, I didnt understand your question:
This line is in Class : def __init__ , like function Bar(text) in my question at top.

Comment: For the third time. **You do not need to, and must not, override `__init__`**. Put that code in `get_form_class`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try Your answer,  and post results later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should override `dispatch` method for such use cases.

```
class Foo(CreateView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something extra here ...
        return super(Foo, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

For your specific scenario, however, you can directly access `self.kwargs` as generic views automatically assign them as an instance variable on the view instance.