# Django getting request get params in Class

Tags: django, django-models

I have a following function:

```
class getAjaxView(BaseDatatableView):

    model = Roles
    columns = model.columns
    order_columns = model.order_columns
    max_display_length = model.max_display_length

    def render_column(self, row, column):
        if column == 'id':
            return '<input type="checkbox" name="cid[]" value="{{$id}}" class="cid_checkbox flat"/>'
        else:
            return super(getAjaxView, self).render_column(row, column)
```

Here the model (Eg: Roles) should come from a GET parameter value and it will change dynamically. How can I access this GET parameter before the function definitions and initialise the variables ?

Comment: Just a hint: usually class names in python are capitalized and don't use verbs. Your `getAjaxView` could be renamed to `AjaxView`.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for noticing me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used [django-datatables-view](https://bitbucket.org/pigletto/django-datatables-view), but if it is based on djangos CBV (class-based views) then you should be able to access the request data like this:

```
def render_column(self, row, column):
    ...
    print(self.request.GET)
    ...
```

---

EDIT: apparently you want to define the `Model` attribute of the CBV dynamicly based on the value of a `request.GET` parameter.

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599145/django-class-view-init), you could try to override the `dispatch` method and use the [`apps.get_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model) function.

```
from django.apps import apps

class AjaxView(BaseDatatableView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = apps.get_model(
            app_label=request.GET.get('app_label', ''),
            model_name=request.GET.get('model_name', ''))

        self.columns = self.model.columns
        self.order_columns = self.model.order_columns
        self.max_display_length = self.model.max_display_length

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I know, I can take like this inside the def. But, I want to get this request.GET parameter before that. I need to get columns, order_columns, etc using the model, for this render_column to work.

Comment: @JintoAntony I updated my answer. Let me know if that brings you closer to solving your problem.

Comment: Yes. That correct and working. I was searching for some thing like this and couldn't find. May be I missed. Can you point me to some references/documentation where this was described ..? I mean using this dispatch...?

Comment: @JintoAntony I did only find it in the stackoverflow question I linked in my edited answer. I'm not sure if I ever saw something like this in the django docs.